# Convert below NOT from EDW to Hive

Tags: hive

```
select source_type, data_load_type from wc_table_inf 
where not (source_type IN ('EHUB','FOCUS','SAPReport') 
and data_load_type in ('FULL','INCR'));
```

This is a EDW query. I need equivalent query in hive. How can i solve this NOT??

Comment: You didn't try googling first?

Comment: yes i did.. But did not found anything

Comment: it is not just NOT IN scenario.. Here we are getting NOT just after where

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`select source_type, data_load_type from wc_table_inf where  source_type not in ('EHUB','FOCUS','SAPReport') and data_load_type not in ('FULL','INCR');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand the Boolean logic `NOT (A and B) = NOT A OR NOT B`

```
SELECT source_type
    ,data_load_type
FROM wc_table_inf
WHERE source_type NOT IN (
        'EHUB'
        ,'FOCUS'
        ,'SAPReport'
        )
    OR data_load_type IN (
        'FULL'
        ,'INCR'
        );
```